# Iron Router Mongo ID Lookup

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I am inserting some information into a mongo collection using this:

      `id = Meteor.uuid();
      subject = $(".msg_textarea").val();
      url = "http://mysite.net/" + id;
       message.insert({
         id: id,
         subject: subject,
         url: url,
      });`

Now what I would like to do is set up an iron-router mapping so that when I visit `http://mysite.net/id/:id` it displays the subject from the collection.

Answer (score 1):

In your route you could have

```
this.route('templatename',
    path: '/id/:id'
    data: function() {
       return message.findOne({_id: this.params.id});
    }
});
```

Then in your template you could use `{{subject}}`